# jquery retrieving value character -

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a response from an ajax request:

```
response.each(function(item, idx) { 
  title = item.meta_title_it-IT;
})
```

The problem is the character "-"  meta_title_it-IT

How can I fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
item["meta_title_it-IT"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets and make the member a string.

```
title = item['meta_title_it-IT'];
```